# Is it possible to add a submodule to a submodule from the top-level git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I'm working on a few game development projects that use the open-source Godot Engine, which supports modules and add-on scripts.

Our team manages a Git repository for the project, as well as some custom engine modules and add-on script Git repositories, but we don't necessarily want to maintain our own fork of the engine for each project if it isn't necessary. Here's the basic structure:

```
/project/project.git                              [The project repo. We maintain it.]

/project/engine/engine.git                        [Open-source engine repo. Submodule. We prefer to not maintain a fork if not needed.]

/project/engine/modules/my-module/my-module.git   [One of our custom engine module repos. Submodule. We maintain them.]
```

In other words, what we'd like to do is add the upstream engine to each of our projects as a submodule at `/project/engine`. And then we'd like to add various modules to the engine under `/project/engine/modules/`, but *as submodules of the top-level project repo instead of the engine repo.*

(Our thought process is that, in many projects, we can simply attach the unmodified, upstream Godot repository directory, and then add functionality to the engine by attaching modules and add-ons. Each top-level project would be responsible for managing the specific engine, modules, and add-ons that it needs. As such, we can cut down on the number of engine forks or branches that we need to maintain, saving that as a last-resort for situations where modules and add-ons can't be used.)

The problem that we've run into so far is that, once we add the engine as a submodule of the project (at `/project/engine`) we don't seem to be able to add another nested submodule (at `/project/engine/modules/my-module` for example) from the top-level "superproject", I think because the target path exists inside the engine's submodule. We want the project to attach a submodule on behalf of the engine, so that the project is responsible for the change but...

**Is that just not possible? Is there no way to add a submodule to the top-level project repository, that targets a path that exists in the one of its submodules?**

I'm open to alternative suggestions if there are better ways to manage this kind of setup, though I feel we're already at risk of over-designing our repo structure here.

Comment: Impossible. A submodule is a separate repository and from Git PoV everything under the submodule's directory — except for its own sub-sub-modules — belongs to the repository and is hidden from the superproject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is on GitHub or on self-hosted Bitbucket, then you can do it with [Git X-Modules](https://gitmodules.com) App - it supports nesting modules, and has a few other features that Git submodules doesn't (such as adding only a specified directory in a repository as a module, etc.).